Constructing confidence intervals using Hoeffding vs. CLT approximation.
I've recently been covering All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman and was interested in comparing the $95%$ confidence interval obtained by Hoeffding's inequality to the $95%$ confidence interval obtained by approximating using CLT, on a sum of binomials.
Namely, let $X_i\sim \text{Binomial}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and let $\bar{X}=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$. We have that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]=\frac{n}{2}$ and $\mathbb{V}[\bar{X}]=\sigma^2=np(1-p)=\frac{n}{4}$.
Using the CLT, the interval lies between $1.96\sigma$ deviations, so this gives the length of the interval to be $$2\cdot\left(1.96\cdot\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}}\right)=1.96\sqrt{n}.$$
Meanwhile Hoeffding gives us that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{\bar{X}}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|\geq \epsilon\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\bar{X}-\frac{n}{2}\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)\leq 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$$
which allows us to construct a confidence interval with $$\epsilon=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\ln\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)}.$$
For $\alpha=0.05$, we have that the length of the interval is $2n\epsilon=\sqrt{2n\ln(40)}$ and since $\sqrt{2\ln(40)}\approx 2.716$, this is a much longer interval than the CLT one.
This goes against what I was expecting, as I thought Hoeffding is more precise. Thinking that CLT is just an approximation, it must give wrong answers, especially for lower $x$. But after summing the discrete outcomes probabilities within the confidence intervals so $I=[\lceil \mu-\sigma\rceil,\lfloor \mu+\sigma\rfloor]$, it seems to be off by $3\%$ at most, while Hoeffding seems to overshoot the mark.

My questions are:

Is there something wrong with my calculations of Hoeffding, it seems the sum of the probabilities of the discrete outcomes within the interval is too high (almost $99.9%$).
In the particular case of the Binomial sample mean, is CLT sharper than Hoeffding for confidence intervals. Can we say anything in the general case for a random variable $X$.
What exactly are the conditions for the general Hoeffding, is it just a finite first moment?


Hoeffding is usually derived for bounded random variables, that is, $a\leq X_n\leq b$ surely. So all moments are finite. There are also versions for "subGaussian" random variables. Your results are probably correct. Hoeffding gives rigorous bounds for all $n$, while CLT is just a good approximation and who knows for what $n$ the result starts kicking in (with higher order info you may be able to say something about this). It does often get results closer to the truth in certain experiments. Theoreticians like Hoeffding because it is correct;  practitioners like CLT because it is often tighter.

Note that part of the error in the normal approximation to the binomial confidence interval is that the normal approximation gives real rather than integer values for the end points.  Taking just that issue into account by rounding the normal approximation confidence interval end points to integer points (either conservatively away from the middle or, more optimistically, to the nearest integers) might be sensible.
